# Very strange... Segmentation Fault because of NAME of int?

Tags: c

When I run this code, I get a segmentation fault, but if I change `result` to `blah` it runs just fine. I've tried every permutation of signed/unsigned, sscanf/atoi, initializing/not, int/char, and even using the pointers directly instead of as an argument.

I know it's the char* are not null. The only change is the name of the variable.

Does anyone know what causes this? It's just plain weird...

EDIT: There are no other variables in the scope of this file.

EDIT: It seems related to the `return`. If I return the value used, I get a fault, but control never leaves the function before crashing.

```
unsigned int getHashValue(char* key, char** table, unsigned int tableCount) 
{
    int i = 0;
    //unsigned int length = strnlen(key,1024);
    unsigned int length = 1024;
    printf("Hashing...\n");
    unsigned int blah;
    int result;

    for (i=0;i<tableCount;i+=2) 
    {
        printf("i: %i\n",i);
        if (strncmp(key,table[i],length)==0) 
        {
            printf("found %s\n", table[i+1]);
            /*sscanf()*/
            result = (unsigned int) atoi(table[i+1]);
            //blah = atoi(table[i+1]);
            //sscanf(table[i+1],"%i",&result);
            return result;
        }
    }

    printf("..done\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably corrupt memory

Comment: Does this code still fail after a reboot? Also, what is your setup/compiler, etc?

Comment: In your code, you are performing a very long string compare `strncmp(key,table[i],length)` where length is 1024. Are you sure that `key` and the `table` are strings of atleast 1024 characters?

Comment: Segmentation fault *where* exactly?

Comment: @Ganesh: `strncmp` stops at the terminating zero or when the requested length is reached - whatever comes first. So, if the strings are zero-terminated, then it is fine if they are shorter than 1024.

Comment: It faults at `result = atoi`. It still failed after reboot. `tableCount` points to a global `char* array[]`. I am using Ubuntu 12.10 64bit on VirtualBox.

Comment: @AndreyT Thanks.. My doubt comes from the implementation. We are comparing 2 strings in `strncmp` where `table[i]` is  string. The final result is being stored as `result = atoi(table[i+1]);` which amounts to `atoi` of a string considering that the length of the string is 1024

Comment: Maybe you should try `for (i=0;i<tableCount/2;i+=2)`, since you appear to have the name/value-items paired in the array. BTW: where is the hash?

Comment: @wildplasser It's declared static in a different file, the one that calls the function. It formatted `static char* hashTable[] = { "name","0","name2","1"...}` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if (strncmp(key,table[i],length)==0)` Since the loop continues while `i < tableCount`, there is a guarantee that i is within the bounds of table, but there is no guarantee that `table[i]` is the pointer to string that strncmp expects. I suggest `if (table[i] != NULL && strncmp(key, table[i], length) == 0) ...` in order to resolve this undefined behaviour.

When a program uses undefined behaviour, it may fail in very strange ways.

There is no guarantee that `i+1` is within the bounds of the array pointed to by `table`. In order to resolve undefined behaviour, please implement proper bounds checks.

Furthermore, there seems to be no guarantee that it points to a string. Consider what `printf("found %s\n", table[i+1]);` might do if `i+1` is within the bounds of `table`, but `table[i+1]` is NULL. The same goes for atoi.

Comment: Ok. Something very odd is happening here. I changed to `if (table[i]!=NULL && strncmp(key,table[i],length)==0` AND I added `if (table[i+1]==NULL) {continue;}` above `result = (unsigned int) atoi(table[i+1])` and it still has the error... If I comment the assignment out, it doesn't crash.

Comment: @user2085142 I already covered this: You need bounds checks to ensure that i+1 is a valid index for table. The valid indexes for table are 0 ... tableCount-1. When i == tableCount-1, i+1 is tableCount, which is outside of those valid indexes. Hence, undefined behaviour and crashy crashy.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I feel ridiculous now because it was in fact returning the correct result and crashing elsewhere. I guess my mind needed a break yesterday!

Comment: @aomimezura This happens to the best of us.